# Margin for splitting a list of images in flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, flowlayoutpanel

I use flowLayoutPanel as a collection of images that come from a list of images which can be clicked and afterwards displayed in bigger pictureBoxes. I wonder if there is any possibility to make a margin in that panel so for example if I want to save those images into one PDF file, I can choose to split a list of images into two lists. I thought about drag and drop or choose method but this one is much easier to use. Here is the code of displaying images from a list into smaller pictureBoxes in flowLayoutPanel :

```
foreach (Image image in images)
{
    PictureBox pf = new PictureBox();
    pf.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
    pf.Height = 150;
    pf.Width = 170;
    pf.Image = image;
    pf.Click += new EventHandler(pictureClicked);
    flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pf);
}
```

And a click method :

```
public PictureBox clickedPicture; 

void pictureClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clickedPicture != null)
        clickedPicture.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    clickedPicture = (PictureBox)sender;
    clickedPicture.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    pictureBoxFront.Image = clickedPicture.Image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
flowLayoutPanel2.margin = new Padding(5);
```

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx

Public Structure Padding
Padding:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.padding.aspx

Comment: I am getting an error saying I am missing a reference for margin.

Comment: I really don't understand that there is no such thing as a simple margin that splits any collection type tool like listBox, panel..

Comment: check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/3z3f9e8b(v=vs.110) if u get any solution for margin